# Stop OpenOffice from removing decimal places

Tags: openoffice

In a table-cell when I type `1.00` and move the focus from the cell **OpenOffice**
removes the *decimal places* from the number and makes it `1`!

[image]

---

> Why is this happening?
>   How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

OpenOffice is interpreting `1.00` a number, not as a string. As trailing decimal places of numbers are redundant so they're automatically stripped off.

> How do I stop this from happening?

- Right-click on table.
- Disable *Number Recognition*.